# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() (array of objects)

Tags: php

I can't get my foreach to work and I have tried everything ...

I have this array ($plugins->response):

```
array (size=1)
  'akismet/akismet.php' => 
    object(stdClass)[108]
      public 'id' => string '15' (length=2)
      public 'slug' => string 'akismet' (length=7)
      public 'plugin' => string 'akismet/akismet.php' (length=19)
      public 'new_version' => string '3.1.3' (length=5)
      public 'url' => string 'https://wordpress.org/plugins/akismet/' (length=38)
      public 'package' => string 'https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/akismet.3.1.3.zip' (length=56)
```

And this is how I try to do :

```
foreach($plugins->response as $plugin)
{
    var_dump($plugin);
    $payload['output'] = $payload['output'] . "\rThe plugin : {$plugin->slug} is not up to date";
    $payload['status'] = 1;
}
```

Do you know why it doesn't work ?
I know it's a basic thing but I promise that's more than one hour I try this to get work. Im pretty new to PHP.
Thanks

Comment: You might have a database that is different than one this code is expecting.

Comment: What does `var_dump($plugins);` outputs?

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>StackOverFlow</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php

class Plugins {

    public $id;
    public $slug;
    public $plugin;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->id = '15';
        $this->slug ='akismet';
        $this->plugin = 'akismet/akismet.php';
    }


}

$plugins = new Plugins();
var_dump($plugins);


// We can iterate the $plugins like this:
foreach ($plugins as $key => $val) {
    echo "$key = $val <br/>";
}
   
// If you want to avoid the iteration and refer to a specific
// property of the object (properties are the public 
//$id,$slug,$plugin) of the class: 
   
$payload['output'] = $payload['output'] . "\rThe plugin : {$plugins->slug} is not up to date";
$payload['status'] = 1;
var_dump($payload);


?>
</body>
</html>
```